# Python - textual - question marks instead of borders in dos prompt

Tags: python, utf-8, textual

I am running my python code in vs code and it displays fine

but in a windows command line I get question marks where borders should display

I use a tutorial code:

```
class Hello(Static):
    BORDER_TITLE = "Hello Widget"

    def on_mount(self) -> None:
        self.next_word()
        self.border_subtitle = "Click for next hello"

    def on_click(self) -> None:
        self.next_word()

    def next_word(self) -> None:
        hello = next(hellos)
        self.update(f"{hello}, [b]World[/b]!")
```

and here is the css

```
CustomWidget {
    width: 40;
    height: 9;
    padding: 1 2;
    background: $panel;
    color: $text;
    border: $secondary tall;
    content-align: center middle;
}
```

so I believe it is an utf-8 issue, but how could I fix this ?

this character ▶ does display as a ?

thanks for your help

Comment: What is the active code page in the terminal (what's the output of `chcp`)? How have you configured Python's output encoding (are you overriding PYTHONIOENCODING or etc)?

Comment: I just found out it is not an utf8 issue but console font/settings https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/how-can-i-use-unicode-characters-on-the-windows-command-line